# jquery tools scrollable destroy reinitialize

Tags: jquery, reset, destroy, scrollable

I use the jQuery tools library and more precisely the scrollable component to make a slider with the navigator function.

```
    // initialize scrollable together with the navigator plugin
$(".scrollable").scrollable().navigator();
```

In a javascript event, I make a ajax request that returns me a slider element that I insert the slider via the additem function.

```
    var api = $(".scrollable").data("scrollable");
  api.addItem($("#newitem").clone()).end();
```

However, the function does not give me full satisfaction, which is why I would like to know if there is a possibility of destroying or reset the slider on an item. I looked in the documentation of the library but I can not find such functions, and remains blocked in the development of my website.

I thought to create a clone of the scrollable element via jquery and then initializing a scrollable on this new element (and then remove the original element) but it does not seem to be a very compelling and optimal solution.

```
$new = $(".scrollable").clone();
$(".scrollable").replaceWith($new);
$(".scrollable").scrollable().navigator();

http://jquerytools.org/documentation/scrollable/
```